# dynamicly add class active to a menu item with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I add "active" class to the "li" tag not the "a" tag.
my code:

```
var url = document.URL;
$('#example li a[href="'+url+'"]').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Alertnative #1 - Select the parent instead of the child

You can use the [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector.

```
var url = document.URL;
$('#example li:has(a[href="'+url+'"])').addClass('active');
```

---

## Alternative #2 - Use a traversing function to get to the parent

You can use the [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) function (if the anchor is the direct child of the list item).

```
var url = document.URL;
$('#example li a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

Another more general option is using the [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function (this would work even if the anchor isn't a direct child of the list item).

```
var url = document.URL;
$('#example li a[href="'+url+'"]').closest("li").addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `parent` function.

```
var url = document.URL;
$('#example li a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose the html is like this:

```
 <div id='example'>
    <li>
       <a></a>
    </li>
 </div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
 var url = document.URL;
     $('#example li a').parent('li').attr('class','active');
     $('#example li a').attr('href',url);
```